# How do I access the data returned in an AJAX call with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I wrote my first AJAX call last week and got it to work, but now I'm writing a different AJAX call and need to access the data returned, not just change something onSuccess.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMessage(jobid) {
         let result;
         new Request.JSON({
             url: '<?php echo site_url('job/getDiscrepancyByJobId/'); ?>/' + jobid,
             dataType: 'text',
             onSuccess: function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
             }
         }).send();
     }
</script>
```

When the script above is called, I get nothing output to the console. I tried doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMessage(jobid) {
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', '<?php echo site_url('job/getDiscrepancyByJobId'); ?>/' + jobid, true);
        request.onload = function() {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
                console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(this.response));
            } else {
                    // Error
            }
        };
        request.send();
    }
</script>
```

but that just outputs `data: ""` to the console.

This is the function that is called:

```
public function getDiscrepancyByJobId($jobid) {
    return $this->MJob->getJobChangeLog($jobid);
}
```

And MJob->getJobChangeLog($jobid) is:

```
function getJobChangeLog($jobid, $limit = 10) {
    if (empty($jobid)) {
        return false;
    }
    $Q = $this->read_db->query('select timestamp, ifnull(t.name, ifnull(u.name, "")) as name, uri, description, postdata, marginchange 
         from jobchangelog l 
         left join user u on u.id=l.userid 
         left join transcriber t on t.id=u.transcriberid 
         where jobid=' . intval($jobid) . '
         order by timestamp desc 
         limit ' . intval($limit));
    return array_map(function($a){ $a['postdata'] = @unserialize($a['postdata']); return $a; }, $Q->result_array());
}
```

The information I'm looking for is in the `@unserialize($a['postdata'])` part and I don't know how to access that either.

Any help would be great. Thank you in advance for your patience.

Comment: `return` in PHP doesn't output a response - show how you call function `getDiscrepancyByJobId` in PHP

Comment: @Bravo, it's in the URL part of the AJAX call. `url: '<?php echo site_url('job/getDiscrepancyByJobId/'); ?>/' + jobid,`

Comment: Should I use `exit(json_encode($this->MJob->getJobChangeLog($jobid)));` instead?

Comment: `echo site_url` does not call `getDiscrepancyByJobId`

Comment: @Bravo, what can I use instead?

Comment: Don't know to be honest as I can't tell how the function `getDiscrepancyByJobId` gets executed in your PHP. `return` could very well be valid, but since the response seems to be empty, either return isn't appropriate, or there's something else wrong in the code that calls that function

Comment: Thanks. I will keep playing with it and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I think your issue is server side code, and you haven't posted enough to get an answer ... most times, you `echo` from PHP to send output in the response

Comment: What happens if you change `return $this->MJob->getJobChangeLog($jobid);` to `echo $this->MJob->getJobChangeLog($jobid);`?

Comment: Sorry, was in a meeting. I get this: `data: <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Array to string conversion</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/Job.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 3287</p>


</div>Array`

Comment: Line number 3287 is `echo $this->MJob->getJobChangeLog($jobid);` in the getDiscrepancyByJobId function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the getDiscrepancyByJobId function to this:

```
public function getDiscrepancyByJobId($jobid) {
    $discrepancy = $this->MJob->getJobChangeLog($jobid);
    echo $discrepancy[0]['postdata']['message'];
}
```

And I changed the AJAX request to this:

```
function showMessage(jobid) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let jid = jobid;
    request.open('GET', '<?php echo site_url('job/getDiscrepancyByJobId'); ?>/' + jobid, true);
    request.onload = function() {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
             console.log(decodeURIComponent(this.response));
        } else {
             // Error
        }
    };
    request.send();
}
```

Thanks for the help!